# Check service status in real-time

Tags: ssh, services

I'd like to check the status of a service in real-time.

I already know the command to check for example my Homebridge server:

```
/etc/init.d/homebridge status
```

When I'm debugging, I'd like to see the change of the status (for example `running` -> `stopped`) immediately.

Is there a command to keep track of this status in real-time, so I don't need to type in the command continuously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`watch`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) utility to continuously update the status without using a loop.

```
watch --interval 1 'date; /etc/init.d/homebridge status'
```

which will update every second (the default is two seconds).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've looked for - a very clean solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a continuous listing of a file with `tail -f`.  I'm not familiar with your specific service, but according [what I see online](https://github.com/nfarina/homebridge/wiki/Homebridge-autostart-at-boot-(init.d)-on-Ubuntu-(linux)), it keeps two logs at `/var/log/homebridge.log` and `/var/log/homebridge.err`.  You would then get the non-error log with this complete command:

```
tail -f /var/log/homebridge.log
```

(or add `sudo` before the whole line if necessary given your permissions).

Comment: Thanks for responding Brick but I really would like to find a way getting exactly this service status in real-time, in order to do some stuff responding to this status. I already worked with the two log files and `tail -f` but it isn't what I need for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Systemd tracks the processes attached to most persistent services, although I am not sure how well with regard to those controlled by old school SysV scripts, as `homebridge` appears to be.

In any case, a simple shell script like this will report that tracking information, including the point at which a process dies/exits for whatever reason.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

while true; do
    clear
    date
    systemctl status $1
    sleep 3
done
```

Call that `monitor.sh` and run it `monitor.sh homebridge`.  The time reported by `date` will change every three seconds if nothing else does. Note this will occupy a terminal until you stop it with Ctrl-C.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed the script a bit and just used `/etc/init.d/$1 status` and it works like a charm. For following readers, don't forget to `sudo chmod +x monitor.sh` before running it with `./monitor.sh homebridge`:-)